# Find and replace parts of a string with string elements from a list

Tags: python

For some reason, my for loop is not working the way I thought it should.  I'm trying to find/match spans in long strings and replace them with a space.  Below are the spans to find in the long strings:

```
items_to_find = ["Hi there, my name is Slim Shady, how can I help",
 "Hi there", "I'm your virtual assistant. How can I help you",
 "Welcome to your virtual assistant, to continue in English, please press one,",
 "Hello, and thank you for calling Shady world. If you'd like ",
 "Assistant"]
```

An example input string into my function:  "Hi there, my name is Slim Shady.  I'm your virtual assistant.  How can I help you.  My I please have your name"

There is at least one outright matches in the above input string.  One other requirement is that I need to case flip the capitalizations in the event that certain words in the text strings are not capitalized (but match the text string otherwise) .  My code (not working):

```
def remove_freq_terms(s:  str):
    for part in s:
        for item.lower() in items_to_find:
            if item in part:
                s.replace(item, ' ')      
        return s
```

The function does not seem to have any effect on the input string when I run it:

```
def remove_freq_terms("Hi there, my name is Slim Shady.  I'm your virtual assistant.  How can I help you.  My I please have your name")
```

The returned string is the same as the input argument.  Also, I have not accounted in this for a way to caseflip(lower) the items_to_find in the for loop (in the event the string match lower case instead of capital letters).  I was thinking the `.lower()` built-in might help here.

I think the answer is somewhere close - I just cannot seem to get the right function built.

Comment: Your code is poorly constructed/carefully think, re-thinking it again. Also string.replace() return the resulting string instead of modifying it

Comment: Thanks Chicky.  The string.replace() method allows you to find the pattern and replace it with a new pattern.  

syntax: string.replace(old, new, count)

Parameters: 

old – old substring you want to replace.
new – new substring which would replace the old substring.
count – (Optional ) the number of times you want to replace the old substring with the new substring.